# setting up fingerprint sensor ubuntu 19.04

Tags: lenovo, 19.04, fingerprint-reader

I cannot figure how out to set up the fingerprint sensor for my Lenovo Yoga 730. I have the latest version of Ubuntu installed (19.04). If anyone has solved this issue, or knows what to do, an answer would be much appreciated :)

I have tried many solutions on here already, and none of them have worked so far.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably worth listing what you've tried so people know not to suggest those options